# Как сделать на странице автоматическое срабатывание элемента?

Tags: javascript, php

Как сделать на странице автоматическое срабатывание элемента button onclick, при выборе в select-е определенного значения и сохранение его на другой странице?

```
<select name="change_status" id="ajax_change_status" class="select">
                    <? if ($subpage == "edit2") { ?>
                        <option value="1">Вернуть заявку в обработку</option>
                    <? } else { ?>
                        <option value="1">Выберите новый статус заявки</option>
                    <? } ?>
                    <option value="2">В кредите отказано</option>
                    <option value="3" <? if (isset($in_bank['status']) && $in_bank['status'] == 3) print 'selected'; ?>>
                        Кредит предоставлен
                    </option>
                    <option value="4">Ошибочный ввод</option>
                    <option value="5">Отказ клиента</option>
                    <option value="8">Отказ клиента по вине ТО</option>
                    <option value="10">Возврат</option>
                </select>


$("#result_html_"+bank+" #"+bank+"_buttons").append('<input type="button" value="Отказаться" class="search_banks_button_red" id="'+bank+'_cancel_button" onclick="cancel_blank(\''+bank+'\', \''+text.idblank+'\')" />');
```

Вот select и сама кнопка, мне нужно при выборе select volue = 5 нажималась кнопка автоматом

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
let select = document.getElementById('select');
select.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (select.value == 'Определенное значение') {
        // то что нужно выполнить
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через localStorage, например, вот так:

**select.html:**

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="1">No message</option>
    <option value="2">Send message</option>
</select>

<script>
    let select = document.getElementById('test');
    select.addEventListener("change", function(){
         localStorage.setItem('click_the_button', this.value);
    }, false);
</script>
```

**target.html:**

```
<button id="clickme">click me!</button>

<script>
    let clickme = document.getElementById('clickme');
    clickme.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert('Button clicked!');
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {
        if(event.key === 'click_the_button' && event.newValue === '2'){
            clickme.click();
            localStorage.setItem('click_the_button', null);
        }
    });
</script>
```